# How to stop DefaultMessageListenerContainer retrying for queue connection?

Tags: java, spring, jms, listener, spring-jms

I am loading spring application(Using spring 2.5 and cannot upgrade to 3.0) context in stand alone application with spring jms like below

```
AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

below is my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destinationName" value="destinationName"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="jmsMessageListener" />
    <property name="exceptionListener" ref="exceptionListener"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="jmsMessageListener" class="Listener"/>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
            <property name="hostName" value="${hostName}"/>
            <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
            <property name="queueManager" value="${queueManager}"/>
            <property name="transportType" value="${transportType}"/>
            <property name="channel" value="${channel}"/> 
   </bean>
    <bean id = "exceptionListener" class="ExceptionListener">

   public class ExceptionListener implements ExceptionListener{
   @Override
public void onException(JMSException arg0) {
     System.out.println("Exception");

}
   }
```

Now, the problem is by default DefaultMessageListenerContainer tries to recover connection with queue until its successful and i can see the message in log file like below

```
INFO [jmsContainer-1] org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection - retrying in 5000 ms: javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager for 'hostName:queueManager'
```

But my requirement is that if it fails to connect my application context should stop loading and i can report an error that it is not able to connect and JMSException is thrown.

I tried using exceptionListener for DMLC but its onException message does not get triggered.

I think I can solve this if I somehow override this default behaviour of DMLC or catch the excetion while loading spring application context.

Can anyone suggest how can i acheive any of the above or if there is any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Put the connection factory and a JMS Template in a separate context. Load that context and attempt to send a message to a (perhaps dummy) queue. If it succeeds, create a new application context with the small context as the parent context (so beans can see the connection factory) set the `configLocations`, and `refresh()` it.

Comment: Thanks Gary.Looks like this is kinda workaround.I dug into spring code and found that refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful() method does not invoke exception listener at all instead it keeps on retrying for connection.Cannot understand why spring folks build it like this..:(

Comment: The exception handler is for handling exceptions when `processing` messages; it has nothing to do with connecting to the broker. As an alternative, use `JmsTemplate.receive()` instead of using the listener container if you want that kind of control.

Comment: My requirement is like that I have to use listener.Its just DMLC implementation is designed that way that it keeps on trying to connect until successful rather to stop/fails if it cannot.